# Is “Can’t be too careful” an idiom?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

> He walked forward and shook the centaur’s hand.
>
> “Good evening to you, Hagrid,” said Ronan. He had a deep,
>   sorrowful voice. “Were you going to shoot me?”
>
> “**Can’t be too careful, Ronan**” said Hagrid, patting his crossbow.

This is a sentence from *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*. I want to know what is meant by the bold sentence. And also what is the subject of that sentence; *I* or *you*?

Comment: It is "idiomatic", but it's meaning is straight-forward -- it implies that an abundance of caution is being exercised.  There is no hidden or metaphorical meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "can't be too careful" is an idiomatic phrase, a shortened version of **"you can't be too careful."**

The phrase simply means that one shouldn't take (unnecessary) risks, that one needs to be watchful, prepared, or prudent:

> **you can't be too careful**: used for saying that it is important not to take risks
>   *You can’t be too careful when it comes to taking financial advice.*

([Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/you-can-t-be-too-careful))

The implied subject, as AllInOne's answer correctly says, is *you*. It's a [generic you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you).

Comment: The OP asked what the subject is and I think it should be I. The other answer says it is *you*. What do you think and why not edit your answer?

Comment: @Rathony I agree with the other answer. I think we have a case of [generic you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you) here.

Comment: I suspected it, too. +1)

Comment: Welcome back A.P. Happy new year. :-)

Comment: Thanks, you too, @Rathony. But I'm "retired" for now :)

Comment: Why? Something happened? You need some rest, not retirement!!!

Comment: Everything's fine, just being on an indefinite hiatus is all. To each his own, my friend.

Answer (score 2):

"Can't be too careful" is a set phrase of very long standing in English and has the meaning "it is impossible [for one] to take too many precautions" or "it is impossible [for one] to take something into consideration too much."

One of the earliest Google Books matches for the phrase appears in a speech by the Lord Keeper in the House of Lords from February 21, 1623, reproduced in [*Journal of the House of Lords*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bCVDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA213&dq=can+not+be+too+careful&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFmNHwu-PJAhVBxWMKHQrxDIw4ChDoAQglMAI#v=onepage&q=can%20not%20be%20too%20careful&f=false), volume 3 (1620–1628):

> His Majesty's Resolution is, the Son of the Bond-woman shall never inherit with the Son of the Free-woman. His Royal Majesty hath given Leave to us that are his Chaplains, to put Him in Mind of this. God is ever careful of Kings, and Kings **cannot be too careful** of him.

Another very early instance is from Francis Beaumont & John Fletcher, [*The Coxcomb*](https://books.google.com/books?id=U1BiAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA17&dq=booty+we+can+not+be+too+careful&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2vofQv-PJAhUB6WMKHRPDBDsQ6AEIPzAF#v=onepage&q=booty%20we%20can%20not%20be%20too%20careful&f=false) (circa 1608–1610):

> *Antonio*. There she shall stand for me; you are Ignorant, this is a common custom of the Rogues that lie about the loose Parts of the City.
>
> *Mercury*. As how?
>
> *Antonio*. To knock at Doors in dead time of Night, and use some feigned Voice to raise Compassion, and when the Doors are open, in they rush, and cut the Throats of all, and take the Booty; we **cannot be too careful**.

---

In the OP's example, the generalized "you"—or "one"—is the implied subject; but the sense of the sentence is "I [Hagrid] can't be too careful."

Comment: Why is this a idiom?  It's not in the sense that the parts don't make sense (like raining cats and dogs).  It means the opposite of "you can be too careful", i.e, you can take precautions that aren't necessary for safety.  Is it an idiomatic usage of an elided subject?

Comment: @deadrat: I will change "idiomatic expression" to "set phrase" because I can't defend the former. Obviously, Hagrid doesn't mean "You [Ronan] can't be too careful"; nor does he seem especially interested in passing along to Ronan a bit of useful folk wisdom regarding the fact that a generalized other person ("you") can't be too careful. Instead he is using the set phrase in lieu of saying "I can't be too careful," which is what he actually means. The misdirection of the implied pronoun might confuse readers like the OP. Thanks for pointing out the problem with my bad choice of terminology.

Comment: I'm wrestling with this myself, which is why I asked.  I think there is something in the "indeterminate" you that can be called idiomatic.  It's almost an inclusive third person:  "in this situation everybody would take all precautions."  And that inclusion encompasses the first person:  "so I would too."  And there's also something not quite analyzable from its parts in "[You] can't be" because obviously you (or whoever) can; it's just that they can't do it safely.

Comment: @deadrat: Yeah... I paused at "idiomatic expression" when I was writing the answer, but stayed with it when "set phrase" didn't come to mind. (Another possibility would have been "proverbial phrase," which to me suggests a piece of an adage that for some reason doesn't rise to the status of a proverb.) The pronoun's behavior here is certainly quirky, as you say, and idioms are nothing if not quirky. But I can't argue that the phrase is idiomatic in a strict sense of that term (as referring to something purely figurative or one-off strange in the usage). Language labels regularly defeat me.

Answer (score 1):

The implied subject of the sentence is *you* or more properly *one*.

As in a rule for living:

> One can't be too careful in life.

(That is, no amount of care is *too much* care)

Similar to the humorous:

> You can never be too rich or too thin.